# Is there a way to write two dataset outputs in single computation in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark job which reads an input File in a dataFrame, does some computation and generates two outputs **processed** and **filtered**.

```
Dataset<Row> input = sparkSession.read().parquet(inputPath);
Dataset<Row> processed = someFunction(input);
Dataset<Row> filtered = processed.filter(someCondition);

processed.write().parquet(outputPath1);
filtered.write().parquet(outputPath2);
```

I observed that during the code execution someFunction() is being called twice(Once while writing processed and other time while writing filtered due to lazy evaluation in spark) .
Is there a way to write both outputs(multiple outputs in general) using a single call to someFunction().

Answer (score 1):

Spark has the ability to [`.persist()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@persist():Dataset.this.type) a dataframe for future computations. By default, it will store the computed dataframe in memory and spill over (temporarily, for the life of the driver) to disk if necessary.

```
Dataset<Row> input = sparkSession.read().parquet(inputPath);
Dataset<Row> processed = someFunction(input).persist();
Dataset<Row> filtered = processed.filter(someCondition);

processed.write().parquet(outputPath1);
filtered.write().parquet(outputPath2);
processed.unpersist();
```

Comment: Is it preferred over .cache()

Comment: I personally prefer it. Without arguments, it's merely an alias. Though using persist allows you to set the storage level as a parameter, if you choose. Also, it's good practice to `.unpersist()` for long running jobs, and using `.persist()` is a more consistent method name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by caching `processed`:

```
Dataset<Row> processed = someFunction(input).cache(); //cache
Dataset<Row> filtered = processed.filter(someCondition);
```

because the data frame used to produce `filtered` is cached, Spark won't need to call `someFunction()` a second time.

Comment: Is cache() better for this use case or persist()(Pointed in answer below).

Comment: No. `cache()` and `persist()` used without parameters are equivalent, they both use the default storage level.